# How can I localize will_paginate in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, will-paginate, ruby-on-rails

I like to localize the "previous" and "next" links in will_paginate, how can I do that?
Did anyone find a nice workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`will_paginate` accepts a Hash of options, including options to customize the previous/next labels.

```
<%= will_paginate @collection, :previous_label => t("previous"), :next_label => t("next") %>
```

Comment: I did that but I get

en, Precedente 1 2 3 EN, PROSSIMO

what's with the "en"?

Comment: I just passing by to say tank you. It yas just what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

In case someone else found the thread..., there is an another solution now.

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/I18n

The following is extracted from the above link.

As of will_paginate v2.3.16 and v3.0, some output of will_paginate view helper and the complete output of page_entries_info helper can be translated by means of the i18n library.

In Rails, this usually means adding your translations in YAML or ruby format in the "config/locale/" directory.

Translation keys and default values for the will_paginate helper can be seen here:

```
en:
  will_paginate:
    previous_label: "Previous"
    next_label: "Next"
    page_gap: "…"
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was downvoted; it seems like an excellent solution to me. (I'm not in a position to test it right now though so I can't say for sure.)

Comment: A nice solution, explained in the gem wiki on github, but seems like something's wrong with it for me. Tried to add a translation in another locale, but it still shows the same output.

Comment: Upgrading from will_paginate 3.0.3 to 3.1.0 seems to have caused it to stop reading the translations in the app. The will_paginate locale file is now the last item in `config.i18n.load_paths` so it overrides the locale in the file.